# How to change windows hostname while launching in amazon cloudformation template

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I want to mention the host name of the instance in the Cloud Formation Template while launching the teplate for a windows instance. How can I do that?

Comment: Please provide more information. Also, please provide details on what have you tried so far.

Comment: I need to modify the hostname of a windows instance from cloud formation template.
I tried doing this as below. It didn't throw any errors but it is not getting executed with CFT. But this command is working when I do it manually.
 "UserData" : {
            "Fn::Base64" : {
                "Fn::Join" : [
                    "",
                    [
                        "<powershell>\n",
                            "Rename-Computer -NewName 'RCT015eng01' -Force -Restart \n",
                        "</powershell>"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }

Comment: Please provide the information as a part of the question. The users who would like to answer might not pay attention to your comments. You can have better chances of reply when you provide adequate information in a properly formatted question.

Answer (score 0):

The user data field is not getting executed since it was not enabled. Need to enable user-data in ec2-config in windows machine and stop the machine and then take the AMI. By using new AMI this would work.